# Вставить перенос строки в текст typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Есть приложение на Angular 6 в котором используется typescript соответственно. Есть кнопка копирования статистики из разных частей страницы. Для копирования написан `ClipboardService` который работает `ClipboardService.copyToClipboard(text);` и с ним все ок.

Проблема в том что данные нужно разделить по строкам так что-бы при вставке их в текстовый файл переносы строк сохранялись. Я пытался делать это так:

```
const text = 'a\nb';
ClipboardService.copyToClipboard(text);
```

Но разделитель копируется в буфер обмена как символ, вместо того чтобы делать перенос строки.

И в файле при вставке вместо:

```
a
b
```

Я получаю:

```
a\nb
```

Как можно реализовать такое поведение чтобы я мог определять где будет перенос строки?

Вот `ClipboardService` на всякий случай:

```
export class ClipboardService {
    static copyToClipboard(toCopy : any) : void {
        document.addEventListener('copy', (e : ClipboardEvent) => {
            const data = JSON.stringify(toCopy)
            e.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', data);
            e.preventDefault();
        });
        document.execCommand('copy');
    }
}
```

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в использовании `JSON.stringify`. Который при применении к строке экранирует спецсимволы.

Если его убрать - то при вставке все будет отлично:

```js
class ClipboardService {
  static copyToClipboard(toCopy) {
    document.addEventListener('copy', (e) => {
      e.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', toCopy);
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log('copied');
    });
    document.execCommand('copy');
  }
}

ClipboardService.copyToClipboard('a\nb');
```